# Camel validate checksum before processing file

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel version 2.20 and the file component with spring boot. My requirement is to validate the MD5 checksum of a file before processing it further (persist data in database using the jpa component). I get the MD5 checksum value in a separate properties file.

I have added the validate method which returns true or false depending on whether the calculated checksum matches the checksum I get from the properties file. But when I am testing this route using the mock message producer, the checksum is always different. I am using the producer.sendBody(Object o) API to send the data. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide more details, maybe some code snippets, and also tell what Camel version you use. Its a bit too hard to help you without more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the md5sum value of the embeded message (your file, in the present case), that way :

```
<from uri="file:/some/full/path/directory"/>
<setHeader headerName="md5sum">
  <groovy>
   import java.security.MessageDigest
   def digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
   def contentMD5 = new 
   BigInteger(1,digest.digest(request.body.getBytes())).toString(16).padLeft(32, "0")
   return "${contentMD5}"
  </groovy>
 </setHeader>
```